Función se ejecuta 2 veces cuando solo se le llama 1
const [matrix, setMatrix] = useState( Array.from({ length: 64 }, () => Array(64).fill(0)));
useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      console.log('Interval tick');
      setMatrix((prevMatrix) => {
        console.log('Matrix state callback');
        const newMatrix = prevMatrix.map((row) => [...row]);
        console.log('Matrix updated');
        iterateSierpinski(newMatrix);
        console.log('Iterate Method called');
        return newMatrix;
      }); 
    }, 1000);
    return () => {  console.log("interval readed"); clearInterval(interval)};
  }, []);


IterateSierpinski solo modifica la matriz. La cosa es que dentro de setMatrix se me duplica todo secuencialmente, es decir se ejecuta todo lo que hay dentro una vez (no se actualiza el valor) y luego se ejecuta otra vez actualizando el valor de matrix. He desabilitado el strict mode de react por lo que eso no es el problema. El problema es cuando en set matrix creo espacios en memoria, como una nueva matriz clonada o inicializada a 0 y la devuelvo. Cuando no creo nada no se dispara 2 veces. Y cuando creo algo y no lo devuelvo tampoco se dispara 2 veces. Es cuando creo algo y lo devuelvo.


Parece un problema de referencias con newMatrix , comparte la declaración de  iterateSierpinski queremos saber que estas haciendo ahí, también menciona si esta declaración de función esta dentro del componente
